# PYTHON call a function after import module finishes

Tags: python, hook, python-module

I want to execute a function once a module is imported. I know I can just call the function directly at the end of the module to achieve this.
For eg..

```
# Inside File Test.py
import something
from test import sayhi

# Lots of functions and classes are defined here

# End of the module
sayhi()
```

But, Since there will be several people changing the file continuously, I do not want to put **sayhi()** at the end of the file but want **sayhi()** to be called once the loading finishes. is there a hook in python that executes once the **import module** statement finishes? I am looking for something like **sys.settrace** with the difference being it should be called only after the **import** finishes.

Comment: you can override the `__import__` hook.

Comment: I don't understand how an import hook has any advantage over a simple function call. You want to avoid the function call because "there will be several people changing the file continuously"? What kind of reason is that?

Comment: Yes, because in my working environment, lot of people continuously change this library file to add their own utility functions. What if somebody defines some functions after sayhi() call. I cannot restrict others from adding code after the call, neither can i check that file everytime a commit is made

Comment: Why don't you just put a comment in the file telling people not to add any code after the sayhi() call?  In Python we rely on the principle that "we're all adults here."